# Spring Boot and Liquidbase separate schemas

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I have a spring boot application which connects to a Postgres SQL database which has 2 separate schemas.

Can I set up Liquidbase to be able to manage/apply changes in the tables that reside in separate shemas inside the same database?

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple SpringLiquibase beans, each with their own changelog files.  For example...

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.schema1")
  public DataSource schema1DataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }
  
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.schema2")
  public DataSource schema2DataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringLiquibase schema1Liquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:/META-INF/liquibase/changelog/schema1-changelog-master.xml");
    liquibase.setDataSource(schema1DataSource());
    return liquibase;
  }
  
  @Bean
  public SpringLiquibase schema2Liquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:/META-INF/liquibase/changelog/schema2-changelog-master.xml");
    liquibase.setDataSource(schema2DataSource());
    return liquibase;
  }
}
```